# Managing web.config variations on different workplaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-config, web-config-transform

I'm not sure if title is good for a problem I'm facing, so feel free to correct it if there is better term for that situation.

Basically I'm struggling with the follwing problem. I work on a project on two different workplaces. The problem is that I have two different connection strings in my `Web.config` file because I have different server names. So it's a pain to work under source control.

So I've tried to use config transformations, but they only work then you do publish, and not then you run locally with `F5`. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice extension that should do it: [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Comment: So basically there is no way to do this using VS built-in features?

Comment: Yes, it's like that out of the box - Xml/Config transforms are for publishing only.

Comment: Actually, there is, if you want to do it without adding any extensions, but it's quite cumbersome: http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2012/01/13/enabling-web-transforms-when-debugging-asp-net-apps/

Comment: SlowCheetah "doesn't work"™ with a `Web.config` files. Will try second solution.